# React : trouble with setState in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I got a warning when trying to fetch data in componentWillMount for server side rendering:

**Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounting component. This usually means you called setState() outside componentWillMount() on the server. This is a no-op.**

here are the code snippets:

```
  async fetchProductsSSR() {
    var response = await fetch(BACKEND_URL + '/products/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    var result = false;
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(response.status);

    if (response.status === 200) {
    }
    else {
      data = [];
    }
    return data;
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    if (!process.browser) {
      var data = await this.fetchProductsSSR();
      this.setState({
        product_data: data
      });
    }
  }
```

I'm sure the data was correct before invoke this.setState.

if hard code the JSON data, everything is fine

```
  async componentWillMount() {
    if (!process.browser) {
   // var data = await this.fetchProductsSSR();

      var data = [
        {
        "name": "Test",
        }
      ]

      this.setState({
        product_data: data
      });
    }
  }
```

I don't know what's wrong and please advice,
thank you.

Comment: Why don’t you make that ajax call in componentDidMount? You have to know that is recommended to make ajax request in the componentDidMount method because this.setState will re render the component and if you make the ajax request in componentWillMount the component is not rendered and there wont be anything to update.

Comment: The above comment is correct but to fix your issue, just do the setState when data is defined i.e `if(data) this.setState({product_data: data })`. This makes sure you don't try to set an undefined value as state

Comment: @Kenji, the reason to fetch data in componentWillMount is server side rendering. I need whole page ready when presented to user.

Comment: @Komolafe, I checked the data and sure that they were good. Just wondering why I am still getting the warning.

Comment: The page won’t be ready because componentWillMount executes just before mounting the component, I mean, the page is blank when that method is executed.

Comment: @winxp1981 It is possible that your AJAX call completes before the component is rendered as you can find in [this discussion](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/constructor-vs-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/4287). Given that you are server-side rendering your component and you need all the data before it renders it could help you to fetch the data in the server and pass it as `props` to your component.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kenji's comment... You have to do that in ComponentDidMount...

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

and if you want to show a loading message you can set loading state and use that condition in render function like...

```
constructor(){
  this.state={loading:true}
}
ComponentDidMount(){
 //do your async thing and change the state to loading:false
}
render(){
   if(this.state.loading)
   return <YourMessage />

   return <Something />
}
```